# Counterexample to Converse of Extreme Value Theorem?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, compactness

The extreme value theorem says:
If $X$ is a compact topological space, then for all functions $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ is continuous we have that $f$ satisfies the extreme value property.  That is, if $f$ is continuous then there exists a point $c$ in $X$ such that $f(c)= \sup \{f(x) : x \in X \}$, where this supremum is necessarily finite.

My question is: Does the converse of this theorem hold in general?  That is, if every continuous function on a space $X$ has the extreme value property, then is $X$ compact?  Or is it instead true that there exists a topological space $X$ which is not compact but such that every continuous function on $X$ has the extreme value property?  If the latter is true, I would like an example.  If the former is true, a proof would be ideal.

Thanks!

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181367/pseudocompactness-does-not-imply-compactness

Comment: Thanks!  The example of the "particular point topology" works perfectly.