# Intuition Behind Compactification

Tags: general-topology, compactness, intuition

I'm heading into my second semester of analysis, and I still don't have a good intuition of when a set is compact. I know two definitions, covering compact and sequentially compact, but both of those seem very difficult to apply "real time". In $\mathbb{R}^n$ I know we have Heine-Borel, which is a very easy way to check things, but I would like to know a different way to easily check for compactness, if there is one.

For instance, can you compactify *any* space? Compactifying Euclidean Space is easy to understand because of Heine-Borel, but can you compactify, for instance, $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the discrete metric?

Comment: Possibly relevant: [pseudocompactness does not imply compactness](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181367/pseudocompactness-does-not-imply-compactness). A *pseudocompact* space $X$ is one where every continuous real-valued function on $X$ has a bounded range. The Heine-Borel theorem is a sort of converse to this.

Comment: @MJD Compactness in $\mathbb R$ is equivalent to pseudocompactness, so Heine Borel says closed and bounded iff pseudocompact.

Answer (score 2):

Heine-Borel is probably close to the best intuition that one can get, at least for Hausdorff spaces.  Compact spaces have a closed, finite character to them.

There are general ways to compactify any topological space, but many of these compactifications are very large and artificial.  The Stone–Čech compactification is the most general and most outrageous.

For $X=\mathbb{R}^2$ with the discrete topology, we have a locally compact Hausdorff space, so we can use the one-point compactification.  That is, we add a point "at infinity", whose open neighborhoods each contain all but finitely many points of $X$.  This example is not very easy to visualize, but it is philosophically very similar to adding a point to $\mathbb{R}^2$ to obtain $S^2$.

Comment: Artificial and outrageous but very cool!

Comment: Why is it locally compact? 
And @TomCruise, what is very cool- the Stone-Cech compactification?

Comment: @Anthony Locally, a discrete space is finite, and finite spaces are compact.  Stone–Čech is very interesting in logic, and when doing universal constructions, but in my opinion it is not very geometric.

Comment: @Anthony Yes, you can find many interesting combinations of topological properties by studying them.  Although they are not so applicable to analysis... the Stone-Cech compactifications of $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb R$ are not even metrizable.

Comment: One more quick question, what is a metric (or a topology?) where closed and bounded does not imply compact?

Comment: @Anthony the discrete metric, for one

Comment: But didn't @you-sir-33433 just say that the discrete metric is locally compact? What is a counter example, a situation where you have a closed and bounded set in the discrete metric, that isn't compact.

Comment: @Anthony The discrete metric is **locally** compact, but not compact.  A set in the discrete metric is compact if and only if it is finite, but every subset is both closed and bounded.

Comment: @Anthony: any norm on a infinite-dimensional vector space. For instance $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$ with the norm $$\|f\|_2=\left(\sum_n|f(n)|^2\right)^{1/2}.$$ In this space, the closed unit ball is closed and bounded but not compact.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Why is that not compact?

Comment: @Anthony: Unfortunately, "boundedness" is really a property of the particular metric and not of the topology it generates. Every metric space $(X,d)$ can be made into a bounded metric space $(X,\hat{d})$ by taking $\hat{d} = \min(d,1)$. You can confirm that $d$ and $\hat{d}$ generate the same topology. The idea is that the important part of the metric is what happens "in the small", not far away. But there are other notions that supplant boundedness (such as total boundedness) that work as well in the definition of compact.

Comment: @Anthony: because you can construct infinitely many disjoint balls of the same radius inside the set (small balls in the "tips" of infinitely many pairwise orthogonal vectors).

Answer (score 2):

There's a few different questions going on here, but I'll focus on the last one:

Yes, it is possible to compactify any space.  An easy way to do so is to take your space $X$ and add a point called "$\infty$", and we say that a set $G$ containing $\infty$ is open if and only if $(X \cup \{\infty\}) \setminus G$ is a compact set in $X$ (and therefore in $X \cup \{\infty\}$).  This is called the "one-point compactification".

So, taking your example: the only compact sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$ under the discrete metric are those with finitely many points.  So, we can take the compactification $\mathbb{R}^2 \cup \{\infty\}$ by saying that we only call a set containing $\infty$ open if it contains all but finitely many of the elements of $\mathbb{R}^2$.  Notice that this is very much distinct from the discrete topology on $\mathbb{R}^2 \cup \{\infty\}$.

Comment: There are usually conditions on $G$ that are required for it to be suitable for one-point compactification. My memory says is should be locally compact, noncompact, and Hausdorff.  I don't remember if these are actually required, but I think at least the local compactness *is* required.

Comment: @MJD for $\mathbb{R}^2$ under the discrete metric, $\{x\}$ is an compact neighborhood of $x$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$, so we do have local compactness.  That the other two properties hold should be clear.

Comment: I am not quibbling with your construction for the compactification of the discrete topology, only with your claim that “it is possible to compactify **any** space. An easy way to do this is [one-point compactification]”. This is misleading unless is is actually possible to use the one-point compactification to compactify any space.

Comment: @MJD oh, I see. Fair point.

Comment: @MJD I think those are only required if we specify that the one-point compactification should be Hausdorff, which is not universally the practice.

Answer (score 1):

A compactification of a Hausdorff space $X$ is a compact Hausdorff $\alpha X$ containing a dense copy of $X$, i.e., cl$_{\alpha X} X=\alpha X$. So for instance $[0,1]$ is a compactification of $(0,1)$.

I think the general idea is you want to embed (put a copy) a space into a compact space because compact spaces are nice to work with.  If you have a *dense* embedding of $X$ into a compact space $\alpha X$, then in a sense $\alpha X$ closely resembles $X$.  To get existence results we usually require $X$ and $\alpha X$ to be at least Hausdorff.

It may seem counterintuitive to get a compact space by *adding* points to a non-compact space.  The important thing for compactness is not the underlying set, but rather the topology you place on this set extension.

Heine-Borel is a very effective tool to check for compactness in $\mathbb R ^n$.  Usually boundedness is easy to determine.  If the set is bounded, it boils down to showing it is  closed.