# $X$ is compact Hausdorff iff it is pseudocompact and realcompact

Tags: general-topology, compactness, examples-counterexamples, realcompact-spaces

I just read this article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Realcompact_space. I am interested with a property: $X$ is compact Hausdorff iff it is pseudocompact and realcompact.

I don't know how to prove this property. Since have not this book "Engelking, Ryszard (1968). Outline of General Topology."  So, please help me to prove it.

According this property we can conclude that pseudocompact Hausdorff is not always compact. But I failed to construct a counterexample. Please provided me an example showed pseudocompact Hausdorff is not always compact.

Answer (score 2):

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/181367/4280) has some answers with examples of non-compact pseudocompact Hausdorff (even normal or better, some of them) spaces.

Another nice example (not mentioned in the above answer, which has several) is the following subset of $[0,1]^I$ in the product topology, where $I$ is uncountable: $\Sigma = \{f: I \rightarrow [0,1]: |\{x: f(x) \neq 0 \}| \le \aleph_0 \}$, the so-called Sigma-product of the uncountably many copies of $[0,1]$. This is a proper dense subset of $[0,1]^I$, so not compact, but any real-valued function on $\Sigma$ depends on countably many coordinates, so is essentially defined on a compact set, so is bounded. (details omitted, but can be found online).

As to the realcompactness, this is not very elementary, and expects some background in the Cech-Stone compactification etc. So it will depend on what you already know. But there is one argument, assuming some background. Suppose $X$ is compact. Then $X$ is pseudocompact (because for every real-valued continuous $f$ defined on $X$, $f[X] \subset \mathbb{R}$ is compact, hence bounded) and realcompact (as $X = \beta(X)$ so $X = \nu(X)$ as well, where the latter the real-compactification of $X$). On the other hand, if $X$ is realcompact and $X$ is non-compact, there exists some real-valued continuous function $f$ on $X$ that cannot be extended to $\beta(X)$ (because we then have $X = \nu(X) \subseteq \beta(X), \beta(X)\setminus \nu(X) \neq \emptyset$, and $\nu(X)$ is maximal with the real-valued extension property). But this function then cannot be bounded, as then we could have extended it to $\beta(X)$. So $X$ is not pseudocompact.

Comment: is the space $\sigma$ realcompact? If so, then $X\neq\beta X$. Hence, there exists a continuous function $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which cannot be continuously extended over $\beta X$. So, the function $f$ is not bounded. Thus $X$ is not pseudocompact

Comment: Like I said, it's pseudocompact but not compact. So it can't be realcompact. The theorem you quoted already says that.