# The space of continuous fuctions is compact - Other direction!

Tags: general-topology, functions, continuity, compactness

we all know that if $X$ is a compact topological space then $F(X)$ is compact for all $F\colon X\to \mathbb{R}$ continuous. I was wondering whether the converse is true? For metric spaces I have found a proof, one can argue by contradiction and use the metric to construct an unbounded continuous function. But the the topological case, I have no clue? Does it still hold? Do we need some strong stuff like Tychonoff?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes, I thought for a moment the OP was just talking about an arbitrary map $X \to Y$ rather than specifically $X \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/181367/212120) is related, but is not an exact duplicate because it only talks about _bounded_ ranges.

Answer (score 3):

The [first uncountable ordinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_uncountable_ordinal) $\omega_1$, with the order topology is not compact. Actually, an ordinal $\alpha$ is compact in the order topology iff it is of the form $\beta+1$, or equivalently, it has a maximum.

Now,  $\omega_1$ has the following property: Every continuous function $f:\omega_1\to\mathbb{R}$ is eventually constant. Hence there exists some $\beta\in\omega_1$ such that for all $\xi\geq\beta$, $f(\xi)=f(\beta)$; in particular, $f[\omega_1]=f[\{0,\dots,\beta\}]=f[\beta+1]$. Since the latter subspace is compact, the range of $f$ is compact in $\mathbb{R}$.

The Wikipedia article about [pseudocompactness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocompact_space) has some info concerning additional hypothesis.